# Drawing on Ipad

Tags: ios, drawing

Actually we are devloping an application which shows remote desktop of the server which recieves mouse points from Ipad and performs annotationns/drawing. The same drawing is also performed on Ipad so that user has a proper drawing experience with out delay. But the drawings in Ipad dont sync with the drawings on server. tkanzakic we are using the same logic to retrieve touch points. This woirks well when we perform slow annotations but when speed of performing annotation is increased, all the touch points are not captured, hence not showing smooth annotations

We are devloping the application in monotouch.

Comment: please modify or clarify your original question if it hasnt been answered well enough rather than raising a second one.

Comment: to check this [reference for iOS  drawing application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121184/ios-open-source-drawing-application-source-code